# Adding Overlay in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, overlay, jsplumb

I am using jsplumb to create a flow-chat. Once the flow-chart creation is over and acknowledged by the user I want to make the created structure un-editable.
For this, have added an overly to the parent  that holds the flow-chart, but the mouse clicks are still happening on the flow-chart.

How to - not allow the mouse clicks happen on these components after adding the overlay.

Thank you

Comment: This is not enough information to answer your question. I suggest providing a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: First of all, I would make your overlay a bright colour, so you can be sure that it's in the right place. Make sure the z-index is high enough so it appears in front, and then try attaching a click eventhandler that calls the javascript equivelent of `event.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler to the overlay that swallows all click events:

```
document.getElementById('yourOverlayID').onclick = function () {
    return false;
};
```

Keep in mind that anyone can simply remove the overlay via the console and continue modifying the chart if they desire. You may want to look at the jsplump API for a way to do this instead, such as [unbind()](http://www.jsplumb.org/apidocs/files/jquery-jsPlumb-1-3-16-all-js.html#unbind).

Comment: Thanks for the information.
I also wanted to disable the mouse drag also, so that users will not drag the connector and connect to another end-point

Comment: Once the user acknowledges what he has done with the editing, i am executing the below code (similar code for document.onmousedown, document.onmouseup , document.onmousedrag), but still the components behind the overlay are still receiving the mouse events.

'document.onmouseup  = function () {
   document.onmouseup = null;
   return false;
}'

Am I missing anything?

Comment: @NagendarReddy that's not an overlay, and a new plugin like this will most likely not bind any events to the `document`, nor bind them in that way.